# Can text in a lookup column be displayed as text with no link?

Tags: 2007, list, lookup-column

SharePoint 2007 and have site curate access only.

List-A has a column Name and that is a lookup to List-B, which only has names and no other information.

Now when looking at lookup columns in views the option displayed is a link to parent list.  In my case List-B has not other info other then names but the names change frequently.  And this lookup is used in many lists.

Is there any way to prevent a lookup column from being clickable so that the value looks like plain text in views?

Answer (score 1):

1)go to list setting -> click on lookup column -> in that, select your which be lookup(without linked to item)

2)
or you can remove link using jquery

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I was inadvertently using option 1 you suggested yet the outcome is still clickable for some reason.

For option two I am assuming it's a CEWP with some code but I don't have a clue about jquery/javascript so any help would be appreciated.

This is more of a want then a need.  Someone asked me about making this unclickable so I am researching it.

Answer (score 0):

please look into this link and get the solution

http://aleemsheikh.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/remove-hyperlink-from-lookup-column-in-sharepoint/